# Why does my money converge to zero?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I invest $\$1000$ in a stock. Every year, the stock price will either increase by $90\%$ or decrease by $50\%$.

The expected value of the change in the price is: $0.5\cdot90\% + 0.5\cdot(-50\%)= 20\% $

I ran a simulation in excel and I got that the stock price converges to zero.

Can someone explain why, or how could I calculate it?

Comment: In your calculations involving $90$% are you using $0.9$ or $1.9$?

Comment: How did you simulate it?

Comment: @graydad I'm using 1.9.

Comment: If you think of it as a Markov chain, 0 is the absorption point. That means as the number of iterations (years) approaches infinity, the state of the chain (price) will inevitably reach the absorption state.

Comment: @Genomeme I generated 5000 uniformly distributed random numbers between 0 and 1, then I multiplied the stock price of the previous year with 1.9 if the number was less then 0.5 and with 0.5 if the number was bigger than 0.5.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Out of curiosity run it with 2.1 instead of 1.9. Let me know what you get.

Comment: @Genomeme I re run it with 2.1. It goes to infinity then.

Comment: Now run it with 2.0 a few times, and I will tell you what I think is happening.

Comment: @Genomome With 2.0 it sometimes converges to 0, sometimes to infinity

Comment: Thought expereiment: What if it either doubled (increase 100%) or went to 0 (0%). With your calculations, you would say it increases 50% on average. Does that make sense?

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio explains what I had in mind. Look at his answer. That is, your simulation are running like they should. There is nothing wrong.

Comment: Maybe you're bad at business

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every year, the value of the stock gets halved or less-than-doubled, i.e. its value gets multiplied by $\frac{19}{10}<2$. Assuming that the two events happen with the same probability, the average value of the stock after $n$ years is given by:
$$\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\cdot\left(\frac{19}{10}\right)^{n-k} = \left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{19}{10}}{2}\right)^n =\left(1+\frac{1}{5}\right)^n.$$
However, with probability $\geq\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ the number of times the value gets halved exceeds the number of times the value gets multiplied by $\frac{19}{10}$, hence with probability $\geq\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ the value after $n$ years is less than $\left(\frac{19}{20}\right)^{n/2}$, that drops pretty fast to zero. So, despite the fact that the average value of our stock increases every year, we are almost surely ruined.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the number of times the value gets halved exceeds the number of times the value gets multiplied by $\frac{19}{10}$? And where does the $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ come from?

Comment: @kanbhold: It is the same problem as the following one: compute the probability that after $n$ tosses of a fair coin the number of heads exceeds the number of tails. By symmetry, we just have to compute the probability that the two numbers are equal: such an event can occur only if $n=2m$, and in such a case the probability is $$\frac{\binom{2m}{m}}{4^m}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi m}}.$$

Comment: and where does that  $\left(\frac{19}{20}\right)^{n/2}$ come from?

Comment: @kanbhold: If the amount gets halved more than $n/2$ times, then it is multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$ more than $n/2$ times, and by $\frac{19}{10}$ less than $n/2$ times, so its final value is less than $\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{19}{10}\right)^{n/2}$.